# Rearrange ArrayList in Alphabetical Order

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the best way to rearrange an arraylist of terms so that `Term('C',1),Term('H',1)Term('C',1),Term('H',1)Term('C',1),Term('H',1) turns into Term('C',1),Term('C',1),Term('C',1),Term('H',1),Term('H',1),Term('H',1)`

My code so far is below: and I don't want to use collections:

```
    public void makeMolecular()
{
    Term define = null;
    char testAlpha = 'Z';
    int testAtoms = 0;
    int remember = 0;
    Term replacer = null;
    int increase = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < terms.size(); j++){
        if (j < terms.size()){
           for(int i = 0 + increase; i<terms.size(); i++){
              Term termX = terms.get(i);
              char charX = termX.getElement();
              int intX = termX.getAtoms();
              if (charX < testAlpha){
                  testAlpha = charX;
                  testAtoms = intX;
                  define = termX;
                  remember = i;
              }
              else {
                  continue;
              } 
           }
           terms.remove(remember);
           terms.add(0,define);
           increase = increase+1;
           //System.out.println(terms);
        } 
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(terms);        
}
```

This current code keeps printing the correct first iteration, but stuff up after that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Term Object has a accessor for the code....

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return o1.getTermCode() > (o2.getTermCode();
    }
}
```

Then call it with something like

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new CustomComparator());
```

Comment: Yeah I know about this, but I have to do it using for loops.

Comment: So you have to implement some kind of bubble sort I am guessing